# Debian does not boot after installation

Tags: debian, acpi

I had Fedora on a HDD and Windows on another HDD. I decided to change from Fedora to Debian and now after installation Debian does not boot.

Here the error messages that it displays to me:

```
[    0.019679] ACPI Error: [\_SB_.PCIO.XHC_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160831/dswload-210)
[    0.019681] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20160831/psobject-238)
[    0.019716] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:xh_rvp08) while loading table (20160831/tbxfload-228)
[    0.025840] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 7 successful (20160831/tbxfload-246)
/dev/sda2: recovering journal
/dev/sda2: clean, 144851/121020416 files, 8908502/484074496 blocks
```

It stucks on this and does not do anything after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with how I plugged my monitor. It was plugged to my graphical card (with a DVI wire) and to my motherboard (with a VGA wire). It worked fine on Windows because I duplicated the display on both. I didn't had that problem on Fedora, I don't know why.

The line

```
/dev/sda2: clean, 144851/121020416 files, 8908502/484074496 blocks
```

indicates that there were no problem during the boot phase.